# Firebird deactivate triggers

Tags: delphi, firebird

I have clients-->|cascade rule|-->orders_table-->|cascade rule|-->order_details
in my order_details I have after delete trigger that increment the quantity in my product table

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TABLEAU_DETAIL_VENTES_AD0 FOR TABLEAU_DETAIL_VENTES
ACTIVE AFTER DELETE POSITION 0
AS
   declare variable qte numeric_15_2;
begin
   select qte_article from tableau_articles where id_article = old.id_article
   into :qte;
   qte = :qte + old.qte;
   update tableau_articles
   set    qte_article = :qte
   where  id_article = old.id_article;
end
```

If I delete a client than all orders depending on it will be deleted
and the orders_detail so on.

The problem is that order_details after delete trigger will be fired and incrementing the product quantity I don't want that to happen.

My question: is there any way to know if the trigger has been fired by cascade rule or sql delete statement that come from the application?

I want to achieve something like:

If trigger triggered by the cascade rule then disable_all_triggers. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe you can use [`RDB$SET_CONTEXT`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-set_context.html) and [`RDB$GET_CONTEXT`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-get_context.html) to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I end up using context variables in my clients table i add after delete trigger and set a flag using `rdb$set_context`

```
SET TERM ^ ;
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TABLEAU_CLIENTS_AD0 FOR TABLEAU_CLIENTS
ACTIVE AFTER DELETE POSITION 0
AS
  declare variable id integer;
begin
   execute statement 'select rdb$set_context(''USER_SESSION'', ''myvar'', 100) from rdb$database' into :id;
end
^
SET TERM ; ^
```

in the detail orders i check my flag with `rdb$get_context` and skip the trigger if the flag exist with the value associated

```
select rdb$get_context('USER_SESSION', 'myvar') from rdb$database into :i;
if (i = 100) then exit;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to wrap your delete code in stored procedure with execute statement for in/activate the trigers

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteClient(
  ID INTEGER)
AS
begin
  execute statement 'alter trigger TABLEAU_DETAIL_VENTES_AD0 inactive;';
  /*
   Your Delete statement here
  */
  execute statement  'alter trigger TABLEAU_DETAIL_VENTES_AD0 active;';
END^
```

Comment: i think i'll use this solution i'll set up all rules to no action and create my own referential integrity using stored procedures

Comment: I'd strongly suggest not to use this: this could disable the triggers for all users!

Comment: As @Mark said in his initial comment, there is a [`per transaction way`](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq189/) using context variables. Your procedure will set a context variable when you start a transaction and inside the trigger you'll check that context variable and skip what you need if it's in a certain value.

Comment: @S.FATEH Yes, but potentially multiple database connections, each could be affected.

Answer (score 0):

You can't determine that, but you can determine if your foreign key is still valid. Since Firebird cascaded deletes are sequential (rows that are referenced in a foreign keys are deleted first), you can check if your `old.id_article` is still valid before updating the record.

Comment: i think you misunderstood the probleme the trigger work fine thank's

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you would achieve what you want like that. What if you just delete an order and its items. Wouldn't you want to increment quantities in that case?

Anyway... I wouldn't deactivate triggers from within triggers. That is bad design.

Use some sort of variable... update a flag in a support table. From within the client delete trigger you can set this variable. Then in the order_items delete trigger you can check it to see if you need to update quantities.

Another better option is to analyze the situation better and determine why and when you actually want to update quantities. If you are deleting an old order which has already been fulfilled and delivered, you probably wouldn't want to. If you are canceling a new order, you probably would. So maybe updating the quantities depends actually more on the state of the order (or some other variable) then simply on the fact that you are deleting an order_items row.

Ok, so you say orders cannot be deleted, except when deleting the client. Then maybe you should flag the client or its order with a flag that states the client is being deleted. In the order_items delete trigger you update article quantities only if the client is not being deleted.

Comment: @
Frazz in my application the orders can't be deleted but only canceled and archived as canceled orders but you could delete/insert/update items if you want 
in my situation if the user want to delete client than it's strange to leave  orders without client !! if i rely on firebird dependencies the quantity will be incremented as if the product returned from client i want to get rid of client and all what are related with it without affecting the quantity

Comment: Deactivating the trigger is not an option in my opinion. I seriously doubt you could do that within one transaction, while other transactions keep having the trigger active. Triggers are for data integrity and should be considered as constants. The only moment I realize it might be necessary to deactivate triggers is when executing maintenance scripts or the such. And that should be done when the db is offline to users and applications. With the new information you provided, I will update my answer.